# Angular 7 CLI ng generate component error: 'Cannot read property 'sourceRoot' of undefined'

Tags: angular, components, command-line-interface, angular7, generate

I was receiving the following error when I tried to run the following command on the CLI:

```
ng generate component [component-name]
```

I kept getting:

```
Cannot read property 'sourceRoot' of undefined
```

I am guessing I started getting it after updating the version of angular I was on. [image: Cannot read property 'sourceRoot' of undefined]

See reply for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I had to go to my Angular.json folder.

1. Search "e2e"
2. Update the 'root' from 'e2e/' to '/'.
   The location is under '[project-name]-e2e'

[image]

Once updated I was able to run the command

```
ng generate component [component-name]
```

No issues came up

[image: ng generate component product-search]